# C. CS50 recover assignment, recovering Jpg images

Tags: c, jpeg, recover, file-recovery, cs50

I have a question about how to recover jpg images (it's an assignment for CS50).
My code works for the most part (I believe), however I only get a bunch of thumbnails when I open the jpg's I found.

I've been trying to solve this exercise for quite some time now but I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work. Could somebody give me a push into the right direction.

Here is my code (also available at http://pastebin.com/U2pwJd5e):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bmp.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    //get input file
    char* infile = "card.raw";
    // open card file
    FILE* inptr;
    inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r");


    // error checking (copied from copy.c)
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // initialize buffer
    BYTE buffer[512];

    //initialize jpg variables:
    int increment = 0;
    char outfilename[8];

    // while the end of the file is not reached, continue process & write to buffer next block of 512 bytes
    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, inptr) != 0)
    {
        // if the inpointer is not empty
        if(inptr != NULL)
        {
            // If the block of 512 bytes starts with markers
            if(buffer[0] == 0xff  && buffer[1] == 0xd8  && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3]== 0xe1 || buffer[3]== 0xe0))
            {
                // increase file number by 1
                sprintf(outfilename,"%.3d.jpg", ++increment);

                // open new file
                FILE* outptr;
                outptr = fopen(outfilename, "a");

                // write first block of 512 bytes, then read next block
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, outptr);

                if(fread(buffer, 512, 1, inptr) == 0)
                       break;

                // copy all information from inpointer to buffer to jpg
                while((buffer[0] != 0xff  && buffer[1] != 0xd8  && buffer[2] != 0xff && (buffer[3]!= 0xe1 || buffer[3]!= 0xe0) ))
                {
                    // if next byte is NULL break
                    if(fread(buffer, 512, 1, inptr) == 0)
                        break;

                    fread(buffer, 512, 1, inptr);

                    //copies jpg file 1 byte at a time
                    fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, outptr);

                }

                // close file
                fclose(outptr);
            }  
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Generally, it is at least arguable that if the code runs, it might belong on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  If it doesn't work, then you need to show the code that isn't working, and maybe a (link to a) sample broken image on which it is failing.  Generally, people don't much like going to another site for the code.  When the operational code is only 70-odd lines long, you can probably paste it here.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of missing information in your problem but I can see a few potential problems:

1. You only check for the JPEG file at the start of each 512 byte block. Unless you are guaranteed that this is the case you should probably check for start of JPEG files in the entire memory block.
2. You only check for JPEG files with a FFD8FFE1 or FFD8FFE0 start. What if the second block in the JPEG is not FFE1/FFE0?
3. The following check in your second `if` block is not correct:

   ```
   (buffer[3] != 0xe1 || buffer[3] != 0xe0)
   ```

   This is always true as `buffer[3]` can't be both 0xE1 and 0xE0 at the same time. This should be:

   ```
   (buffer[3] != 0xe1 && buffer[3] != 0xe0)
   ```
4. Your checking for the end of the JPEG image probably doesn't do what you wanted:

   ```
   while ( buffer[0] != 0xff && buffer[1] != 0xd8 &&
           buffer[2] != 0xff && buffer[3] != 0xe1 && buffer[3]!= 0xe0 )
   ```

   This ends the JPEG when you find *any* of those values at the start of the 512 byte block. For example the bytes 01DB0203 would end the JPEG since `buffer[1] != 0xd8` is false, even though this is not a JPEG block marker.
5. I would think that finding the end of a JPEG file would require you to search the entire memory block for the FFD9 byte marker which signifies the end of a [JPEG file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG). If I understand the JPEG format correct a FFD9 byte combination can only occur at the end of a valid JPEG file.
6. If you still run into issues I would create a test file composed of several known JPEG files and other data. You can then directly compare what is being output to what you know should be output to narrow down where/what is causing the problem.

Comment: The `0xFFE0` is the JFIF signature while the `0xFFE1` is the EXIF. Those will cover more than 99.9% of the Jpeg files out there.